# requestRender doesn't seem to render (opengl-es android)

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, render, game-loop

I have a gameloop running in a thread, my problem is that the

```
mGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
```

crashes with a null pointer exception.  I have a log tag in my onSurfaceCreated method which proves that the surface is created (at least I think) so that's not the problem.

I'm thinking that the problem is that requestRender needs a non-static reference.  When I tried calling a non-static reference to another method it crashed on that line instead. So I can only assume that threads aren't too friendly with non-statics.  I also can't make a static reference to requestRender (which would be an obvious solution).

Here is my game loop thread

```
import android.util.Log;

public class GameLoop extends Thread {

    private MyGLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView;
    private final static int maxFPS = 30;
    private final static int maxFrameSkips = 5;
    private final static int framePeriod = 1000 / maxFPS;

    public static boolean running;
    public final static String TAG = "input";

@Override
public void run() {
    running = LaunchActivity.getRunning();
    long beginTime;
    long timeDiff;
    int sleepTime;
    int framesSkipped;


    sleepTime = 0;
    while (running) {
        running = LaunchActivity.getRunning();
        Log.d(TAG, "gameRunning");
        beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        framesSkipped = 0;
            // notice the static reference here
        GameLogic.update();
        Log.d(TAG, "updated");
            // not static here
        myGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
        Log.d(TAG, "rendered");
        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
        sleepTime = (int)(framePeriod - timeDiff);

        if (sleepTime > 0) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                Log.d(TAG, "sleeping" + String.valueOf(sleepTime));
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }

        while(sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < maxFrameSkips){
            GameLogic.update();
            sleepTime += framePeriod;
            framesSkipped++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Frames Skipped");
        }




}
}


}
```

And here is my surface created method (which I though could be part of the problem at a long shot)

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    Log.d(TAG, "SurfaceCreated");

}
```

Oh and by the way i'm using

```
glOrthof
```

projection

StackTrace

```
10-05 20:26:44.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18276): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
10-05 20:26:44.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18276): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 20:26:44.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18276):     at basicmelon.games.androidgamething.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:33)
10-05 20:26:44.694: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18276):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Log TAG

```
10-05 20:28:23.077: DEBUG/input(18923): GLSurfaceViewed
10-05 20:28:23.116: DEBUG/input(18923): Created
10-05 20:28:23.116: DEBUG/input(18923): Resumed
10-05 20:28:23.124: DEBUG/input(18923): gameRunning
10-05 20:28:23.132: DEBUG/input(18923): Updated
10-05 20:28:23.210: DEBUG/input(18923): Paused
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace from the exception and the log output that shows your log message?

Comment: @P.T. Just Realised that SurfaceCreated log tag is never called (so much for my surface creating properly) and I ammended some on the game loop code (got rid of `= new GLSurfaceView` from the reference to MyGLSurfaceView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never create the MyGLSurfaceView object. You have to put this line somewhere prior to the while-loop:

```
myGLSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView();
```

Comment: any suggestions as to what I should put between the brackets =P

Comment: try: myGLSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this); And probably you should read the documentation of the classes you are using^^

Comment: found this line in my LaunchActivity and brought the variable over ^_^ thank you so much